# Post body retrofit2 include curly brackets

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit2

I wanna post request with body in retrofit, wherein the brackets there is another brackets 
expect body request: `{"attributes":{"data":"FOOBAR"},"deviceId":171,"type":"custom"}`

I've tried with backslash and I always get a bad request.

**Activity.java**

```java
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("{\"data\":\"");
                                stringBuilder.append(commandInput.getText());
                                stringBuilder.append("\"}");

                                Tasker task = new Tasker(idUnit, "custom", stringBuilder.toString());
                                Call<Tasker> call2 = mApiService.postCommand(task);
                                call2.enqueue(new Callback<Tasker>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<Tasker> call, Response<Tasker> response) {
                                        Toast.makeText(CommandActivity.this, getString(R.string.command_sent), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Call<Tasker> call, Throwable t) {
                                        Toast.makeText(CommandActivity.this, getString(R.string.command_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
```

**Tasker.java**

```java
public class Tasker {
    private long deviceId;
    private String type;
    private String attributes;

    public Tasker(long deviceId, String type, String attributes) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.type = type;
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

Expect result payload:

```
{"attributes":{"data":"FOOBAR"},"deviceId":171,"type":"custom"}
```

Actual output payload:

```
{"attributes":"{\"data\":\"FOOBAR\"}","deviceId":171,"type":"custom"}
```

Comment: what does `commandInput.getText()`? it seems that you put too many slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You need some class or Map object to hold the attributes, not `String attributes`

Also, try to use JsonObject class rather than just a StringBuilder